# "var_name" VS "var-name" VS "varName" - Which is supported by the widest variety of languages

Tags: variables, naming-conventions, naming

I have seen multi-word variables displayed in 3 ways:

- With an underscore - `var_name`
- With a hyphen - `var-name`
- With capitalization - `varName`

Different languages support different ways. For example, you can use `-` (hyphens) in CSS classnames / IDs, but not in Javascript variable names

My ultimate question is:

Which is most widely supported across different programming languages, and are there any advantages or limitations of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a tie between the underscore '_' and camel case - or capitalization as you call it.  Hyphen gets interpreted as an operator in many languages, so it should be avoided as a common naming tool.

All languages I have used (fortran, pascal, C/C++, Java, PHP, JS, Python) all differentiate and accept capitalization and underscores in variable names.  So, it becomes a matter of preference.  I was taught camelCase through school so that is what I have stuck with.  It creates a bit shorter variable name than inserting underscores and is easier to type.  Having said that, I think names with underscores are a bit more readable, and that is reason enough to use them over others.  If I could get my brain to change it's habits, I would use underscores.

Comment: I was using camel case (I did not know it was called that) until a little while ago. Reading though other code, I can see almost everyone uses `_`. I have now switched all my variable names to underscores. I was actually using `-` for some things (Wordpress / PHP), since they were not variable names, they were stored as a string as a unique identifier. I then found trying to have the same name as a Javascript variable did not work. Thanks for this useful answer!

Comment: Okay, I am inspired.  I am going to start using underscores as well.  I hope my old synapses can be regrown in that direction.